# desire2learn Valence: Course Getting orgUnitID from Offering Code

Tags: desire2learn

I'm doing some work with grades and the desire2learn Valence API.  In the context I'm operating in, there is no way for us to get the orgUnitID directly.  We are currently getting the Offering Code for each course but not the orgUnitID.  Since the API requires the orgUnitID for any interactions with a course, is there any way to look up the orgUnitID using the offering Code for the course?
Thanks,
   George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no call to search for a course by offering code, but, the offering code is set in the [OrgUnitInfo structure](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#Enrollment.OrgUnitInfo). So I have seen people retrieve that structure as an indirection to get the actual ID. (For example when [trying to retrieve grades](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018065/how-do-i-export-grades-from-desire2learn))

If you have a [user id for example](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-enrollments-users-%28D2LID-userId%29-orgUnits-) you could get enrollments and go from there.

To answer further I would need a sense of how you wanted to walk the courses? Globally or for a specific user or something else?

Comment: In one context we have a userID that we are using to look up the orgunitID for the course, but in another we only have the course offering code. . .  The user context of our call is as an administrator, so we are not logged in as the user directly.  Basically here is the scenario:

1. User SSO's from D2L into our system
2. The SSO contains the UserID and course offering code as well as the user's role, etc. We store this information.
3. We are then trying to post assignments back to D2L when the Instructor SSO into our system.

Comment: We don't have the student's userid in the case where we are creating assignments.  This is the case which causes us a problem.  Only in the case where we are posting scores to the assignments.