# How do I use the Desire2learn Valence API to enroll a student in a course?

Tags: desire2learn

In trying to automate a workflow, how do I use the D2L REST API to enroll a student in a course?

Answer (score 0):

D2L works on enrollments that are a tuple of the user, the role and the course or org structure (orgunitid represents course *or* a structural element like a department or faculty).  The [call to create these enrollments](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#post--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-enrollments-) allows you to specify all these values, and other calls allow retreival of the ids for users or courses.

Most often developers need to search by course code, but that is not possible directly on version 9.4.1 or version 10.0 so you will want to locate the d2lid from the course code in the calling code (this [course code search is covered in other questions as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125532/desire2learn-valence-course-getting-orgunitid-from-offering-code)).