# Valence API - Get enrolment(s) by Course Code

Tags: desire2learn

I came across Valence API enrollment methods, they only retrieve enrollment by orgUnitId (12345), there is no method allow to retrieve by course code (COMM101).

Has anyone had inquiries like me and got solution to retrieve enrollments by course code?

In addition, I currently can obtain orgUnitId by look at eLearn URL. 
(https://(eleanurl)/d2l/home/123456)
Is there any better way to obtain orgUnitId?

Much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [desire2learn Valence: Course Getting orgUnitID from Offering Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125532/desire2learn-valence-course-getting-orgunitid-from-offering-code)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Organization Structure page of the Valence API, especially the the [route to call orgstructure](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28version%29-orgstructure-). This route can be called with query parameters, including orgUnitName, which will search for a substring within the name of an organizational unit. The orgUnitType parameter allows the query to be restricted to a particular organizational unit type, so you could limit it to just course type units, which should reduce the time the query needs to run. The return value of this includes orgUnitIds (see [orgUnitProperties](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#OrgUnit.OrgUnitProperties), where the Identifier is the orgUnitId) for each course found matching your query parameters.

You can gather the orgUnitIds from your query and then you can make calls to the enrollment routes for each id.

Comment: Note that, if you know the course code, that should be the `orgUnitCode` for the purposes of filtering on the `/d2l/api/lp/(version)/orgstructure/` collection (it _should_ have been provisioned that way on your Brightspace instance; that's the intended purpose for the property; however, it's not enforced to have used the property that way). You can use the course code you know, to find the D2LID for the org unit that's your course offering, and then you can search for enrollments knowing the D2LID value.