# Valence: get course by Offering Code

Tags: desire2learn, valence

Given just the offering code (something like `ZZ_ZZ666-CLASS_ZZ1_16M5W1`), how can I get the id of a course? For my purposes, there is no user ID to work from, as I don't have access to the roster.

Also, this is being done via a service account, so `myenrollments` won't help.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125532/desire2learn-valence-course-getting-orgunitid-from-offering-code) from a few years back is relevant, but not helpful, as the suggested solution requires a user id.

Any help, D2L folks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon submitting my question, my google-fu instantly leveled up and I found an answer [here](https://community.brightspace.com/devcop/f_technical/is_there_a_way_to_retrieve_orgunitid_of_course_offering_by_course_co)

I'm going to leave this answer here, because I don't think it's been answered on SO yet...

The call:

`/d2l/api/lp/1.4/orgstructure/?orgUnitCode=ZZ_ZZ666-CLASS_ZZ1_15M5W1`

Which is...blindingly simple, really. You can also search by course name.

[Documentation here](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html)