# logging into d2l lms using valence

Tags: valence

I want to authenticate and get a specific course org unit id using valence and java. I have a application id and user key for the application I got from the d2l keytool. I am also using d2l's java client library for authenticating.  i.e. com.d2lvalence.idkeyauth.*;

I am getting a http 403 error on the last line of code.
Can someone see what I doing wrong?

```
        URL url = null;
        URLConnection connection = null;
        String host = "ucbdev.desire2learn.com";
        int port = 443;
        String appID = "from d2l";
        String appKey = "from d2l";
        String userId = "";
        String userKey = "";

        AuthenticationSecurityFactory factory = new AuthenticationSecurityFactory();
        // appID and appKey are from d2l
        ID2LAppContext appContext = factory.createSecurityContext(appID, appKey);

        URI resultUri=new URI("?x_a=fromd2l&x_b=fromd2l");
        ID2LUserContext userContext=appContext.createUserContext(resultUri, host, port, true);
        if (userContext == null){
            System.out.println("USERCONTEXT is NULL");
        }
        System.out.println("USERCONTEXT HOST NAME IS :"+userContext.getHostName());

        userId = userContext.getUserId();
        userKey = userContext.getUserKey();
        System.out.println("userID is "+userId);
        System.out.println("userKey is "+userKey);

        URI newUri = userContext.createAuthenticatedUri("/d2l/api/lp/1.0/orgstructure/", "GET");
        String res = newUri.toString();
        System.out.println("authenticated uri usercontext s "+res);
        connection = newUri.toURL().openConnection();

        //cast the connection to a HttpURLConnection so we can examin the status code
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
        httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

        BufferedReader in = null;
        //if the status code is success then the body is read from the input stream
        if(httpConnection.getResponseCode()==200) {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpConnection.getInputStream()));
        //otherwise the body is read from the output stream
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: " + httpConnection.getResponseCode() + ""); //error 403 here
        //    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpConnection.getErrorStream()));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not seem to be clear on [how the authentication works for the Valence Learning Framework API](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/auth.html).
The AppId/AppKey pair you get back from D2L's KeyTool is the keypair that you'll use to prove that your API call comes from *your app* (i.e. you pass the AppId in the `x_a` parameter on a normal call, and you use the AppKey to generate a signature that you then pass in the `x_c` parameter on the call). But each normal API call also requires user tokens to prove the is being made on behalf of a *known user*:

All our SDKs work in the same general way:

1. First you create an *application context* object that's built using your AppID/Key keypair.
2. Then, you create an "URL for authentication": this URL will be a call to the special ["get user tokens"](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/apiprop.html#get--d2l-auth-api-token) API call (here the `x_a` parameter is your AppId, and the `x_b` parameter is the signature).
3. You direct the user's browser to go to this URL for authentication, and it's `x_target` query parameter specifies the callback URL where the LMS should send the user ID/Key pair after it successfully determines who the user is.
4. Once you have this User ID/Key pair, in subsequent normal API calls, you will pass the User ID in the `x_b` parameter (as you're passing the App Id in the `x_a`) and you will use the User Key to make a signature that you will pass in the `x_d` parameter.

Please follow along the [authentication conceptual topic](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/auth.html) in the docs carefully, as it will show you all the steps involved in the process of your app getting back a UserID/Key pair so you can then use it to make API calls.

Comment: Viktor.  The instructions you refer to require use of a browser based login. The system that needs to be developed is a batch java system with no interaction from a user. An alternative way than using a browser to log into is required.  Here is the sequence: 1) Authenticate  2) get a specific course org unit id  3) update the course title.  This is for about 1000 courses within our desire2learn environment.

Comment: The most common recommendation we make in these cases is to build a utility user/role account pair, given only the permissions and enrollments required to accomplish your task. See this other Stack question for more info (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946274/authenticaton-method-for-desire2learn-rest-api-vs-soap).

Comment: See also this other question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712396/consuming-the-valence-api-as-an-application).